# implementing multi qr code scanning in a stepper, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, qr-code, dart-pub

I'm building a flutter application and i want to scan 2 qr codes in a stepper widget in 2 steps , I'm using the mobile scanner package.
first one is to scan the qr code on the voucher and then display a popup with a progress bar to check if the driver is the authorized to take this order....
and the second is to check the qr code on the vehicle to check if the driver is taking the right vehicle

example of the app :
[stepper implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoYnD.jpg) 
also when i took the screenshot the camera stopped i don't know why xD,
anyway this is my widget tree

```
 Step(
        isActive: _currentStep >= 1,
        state: _currentStep >= 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
        title: Text("Scan Qr code of the Voucher"),
        content: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: MobileScanner(
                  // fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  controller: controller,
                  onDetect: (capture) {
                    _onDetectQRDriver(capture);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Step(
        isActive: _currentStep >= 2,
        state: _currentStep >= 2 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
        title: Text("Scan Qr code of the Truck"),
        content: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: MobileScanner(
                  controller: controller1,
                  onDetect: (capture) {
                    _onDetectQRTruck(capture);

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

this is the `_onDetectQRDriver` function :

```
  Future<void> _onDetectQRDriver(BarcodeCapture capture) async {
    print("------------------------on Driver Detect");
    // await controller.stop();
    print("------------------------on Driver Detect after await");
    final List<Barcode> barcodes = capture.barcodes;
    final Uint8List? image = capture.image;
    for (final barcode in barcodes) {
      debugPrint('Barcode found! ${barcode.rawValue}');
    }
    print("-------------------------------Driver");
    _showDriverCheckingDialog();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      _advanceStep();
    });
  }
```

this is how I'm initializing the controller :

```
  MobileScannerController controller = MobileScannerController(
      facing: CameraFacing.back,
      detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates,
      torchEnabled: false,
      autoStart: false,
  );
```

the problem is that when scanning in the first step the on detect function is being called in both widgets so I'm firing 2 functions when the first qr code is scanned . I've tried to implement 2 controller for each qr scanner widget but didn't work,
can someone please help and guide me on how to implement such flow (1-Scan first qr -> do some verification then proceed to next step (next qr code) and also do some verification....)
regards

Comment: Could you share both controller implementations?

Comment: @Alex of course i will edit the question and include the corresponding code for the controller , also I'm thinking of adding a button on each step instead of the qr code widget directly in each step
So each button will display a popup that will now contain the qr code widget
So we can easily manage the life cycle of it
What do you think?